# ASP.NET MVC3 and Unity - Decouple Unity implementation from presentation layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

Hello and thanks in advance for any help.

I have a question about how I am structuring Unity in my MVC3 application.

At the moment I have modeled my Unity implementation from this useful example code:

http://kevww.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/dependency-injection-with-unity-2-0-in-mvc-3/

I can get it to work fine, but I am asking myself if there is a slightly different approach. In essence the solution calls for two classes, the first a dependency resolver.

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
IUnityContainer _container;

public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
{
_container = container;
}

public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
object instance;
try
{
instance = _container.Resolve(serviceType);
if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
{
return null;
}
return instance;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
return null;
}
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
}
}
```

And a Unity container setup class, with a setup called from Global.asax:

```
public class UnityContainerSetup
{
public static void SetUp()
{
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ISomeService, SomeService>();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
}
```

OK, so my question. Is there a better way to actually decouple this Unity implementation?

I created a separate project and placed the two classes above in it. It worked fine after I referenced `System.Web.Mvc` in that new project to resolve `IDependencyResolver`.

However, that didn't seem to make a lot of sense either if I ever wanted to re-use a common assembly to use Unity from something else, such as a Web Form application using the same repository and DAL.

Or, is this just the plumbing you need to do to get Unity to work? i.e. if I ever change my Unity implementation in my various projects I am just going to have to visit each one in turn? Or is my approach OK for a middle ground compromise?

The obvious problem for me here is that the `IDependencyResolver` is a part of MVC. So I'm not sure how a 'common' assembly for unity could even be done for MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You'll always need the container setup, but rather than using the DependencyResolver directly, you can create a ControllerFactory and register it with MVC. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2.aspx) for an example with Unity.

This allows you to keep all dependencies and resolutions thereof in the Controller and anything you pass to the presentation layer should be a flat model or simple viewdata.